# If $a^{1/x}=k$ then how is $a=k^x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^{1/x}=k$ then how is $a=k^x$?

It's a basic thing but I'm having a little problem understanding this thing.

Comment: I don't need a detailed explanation. If somebody could only replace a,x and k with numbers, I will be thankful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has been helped and the question carries no value to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is wrong.
$$
a^{\frac{1}{x}}=k \Rightarrow  \left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^x=k^x \Rightarrow a=k^x
$$

Comment: Thanks bud! I've edited my question.

Comment: OK. Now my answer is the proof

Comment: Sure it is. Thank you.

Comment: To make it completely self-explanatory, you might want to write it instead as $a^{\frac{1}{x}}=k\Rightarrow\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^x=k^x\Rightarrow(a)^ {\frac{1}{x}\cdot{x}}=k^x\Rightarrow a=k^x$.

Comment: OK! and the most dificult task is to prove that $(a^{1/x})^x=(a)^{x/x} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.